# chromoPlot error - reads more data than in file

Tags: r, genetics

I am trying to use the chromoPlot package in R to visualize chromosome segments.

According to the [guide](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/chromoMap/vignettes/chromoMap.html#prepare-input-data-files) I should make a chromosome file that defines the chromosomes of interest and a data file with segments of interest

then

```
library(chromoMap)
chromoMap("FF Chromosome Map/DB/chromosome_file.txt","FF Chromosome Map/DB/Anne Larsen.txt")
```

should nice draw the segments on the chromosome map.

However I get the error when I try to run the code

```
********************************** __ __ ************
** __**|__ * __* __ * __ __ * __ *|  |  |* __ * __ **
**|__**|  |*|  *|__|*|  |  |*|__|*|  |  |*|_ |*|__|**
***********************************************|   **
*************** by Lakshay Anand ********************
OUTPUT: 
Number of Chromosome sets: 1 
Error in scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,  : 
  line 2 did not have 5 elements
```

when I read the data files manually they have 4 columns each \tab separated as they should.

Any suggestions

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to check your files and make sure there are no column names or row names, and have exactly the format mentioned in the guide. See below:

We can simulate some data and write them as txt files, note no column or row names:

```
df = data.frame(chr=c("chr1","chr2","chr3"),
start=1,end=c(100e6,120e6,80e6),cent=c(50e6,60e6,70e6))
write.table(df,"chromosome_file.txt",quote=F,
sep="\t",row.names=FALSE,col.names=FALSE)
anno = data.frame(Ele=c("Feature1","Feature2"),
chr=c("chr2","chr3"),start=c(50000,55000),
end=c(60000,70000),score=c(77,88))
```

And here's a reproducible example:

```
library(chromoMap)
chromoMap("chromosome_file.txt","anno.txt")
```

[image]

If the table is written with row names or column names, as is the default, I can reproduce your error:

```
write.table(df,"chromosome_file_v2.txt",quote=F,sep="\t")
chromoMap("chromosome_file_v2.txt","anno.txt")
********************************** __ __ ************
** __**|__ * __* __ * __ __ * __ *|  |  |* __ * __ **
**|__**|  |*|  *|__|*|  |  |*|__|*|  |  |*|_ |*|__|**
***********************************************|   **
*************** by Lakshay Anand ********************
OUTPUT: 
Number of Chromosome sets: 1 
Error in scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,  : 
  line 1 did not have 5 elements
```

Comment: You soluted my problem, although I do not why. I have no header and I use the correct  columns. I  guess I have some invalid control characters from my texteditor. However You gave my the idea to read my input files with read.csv and the store them again with write.csv. And then it strangely worked. So thanks for leading my in the right direction (although I still not understand why it went wrong :-) )